# vscode debug pauses on decompiled .class file instead of source .java files

Tags: java, vscode-debugger

This has been bothering me for quite some time and i have yet to find a solution.

When I set a break point in VSCode for debugging java the debugger pauses on the .class files located in the maven target/classes instead of the .java file.

I would like it to use .java just like the way Intellij does it. Its really annoying for me when I find my bug and edit the code then hit replay only to find I edited the code in the .class file instead of the .java. The .class file gets overwrite on the next debug play and you lose all the changes you've just made.

I have found this link below on github that asks the same question but there is no answer
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/915

I am using the Microsoft java extension pack.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the following setup:

vscode multi root workspace with

- project A
- procect B
- project C

Where project A and project B both referenced project C as a dependency in the pom.xml

Now if I would set a breakpoint in .java file of project c and run code from project A it would pause in the .class file. The reason is that project A and B used different versions of project C.

**So my solution was to remove project b from the multi root workspace** (and create a sepearte workspace with only projects B and B)